# Как исправить ошибку, вместо реквизита выводится <>

Tags: 1с

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе реквизита из справочника в документ, вместо ФИО пишется <>. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо работать со стандартным реквизитом "Наименование", а не с отдельным реквизитом.

Comment: Улучшите свой ответ и добавьте в него рабочий код

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что у выбранного элемента справочника Наименование = "<>"

Чтобы исправить, откройте карточку сотрудника, затем заполните ФИО и сохраните изменения.